# When using functions_framework, getting an error "werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'xxx'"

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-functions, jinja2

I would like to deploy my pre-created Flask app to google cloud functions. Of course this app works fine by app.run().

However, when I launch it via functions_framework, the links like "xxx" gives "werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'xxx'".

detail:

```
[2023-10-11 15:25:41,533] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{{ my workspace directory }}\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "{{ my workspace directory }}\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "{{ my workspace directory }}\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "{{ my workspace directory }}\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "{{ my workspace directory }}\env\lib\site-packages\functions_framework\__init__.py", line 130, in view_func
    return function(request._get_current_object())
  File "{{ my workspace directory }}\main.py", line 17, in index
    return render_template("index.html",content = content)
  File "{{ my workspace directory }}\env\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 152, in render_template
    return _render(app, template, context)
  File "{{ my workspace directory }}\env\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 133, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "{{ my workspace directory }}\env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1301, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "{{ my workspace directory }}\env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "{{ my workspace directory }}\templates\index.html", line 10, in top-level template code
    {% include 'sidebar.html' %}
  File "{{ my workspace directory }}\templates\sidebar.html", line 13, in top-level template code
    <li><a href="{{url_for('.index')}}">Home</li>
  File "{{ my workspace directory }}\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1071, in url_for
    return self.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
  File "{{ my workspace directory }}\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1060, in url_for
    rv = url_adapter.build(  # type: ignore[union-attr]
  File "{{ my workspace directory }}\env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing\map.py", line 919, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'index'. Did you mean 'run' instead?
```

**If I remove these links, the error is no longer displayed from the functions_framework, but any routing does not work (only the index page is always displayed).**

I am puzzled because I have no clue. What should I look for and how should I address this?

The modules I am using is below. :

```
PS {{ my workspace directory }}> .\env\Scripts\python.exe -m pip list                                                                           

Package             Version                                                                                                                                                                                
------------------- -------
blinker             1.6.3
click               8.1.7
cloudevents         1.10.0
colorama            0.4.6
deprecation         2.1.0
Flask               3.0.0
functions-framework 3.4.0
itsdangerous        2.1.2
Jinja2              3.1.2
Markdown            3.5
MarkupSafe          2.1.3
packaging           23.2
pip                 23.0.1
setuptools          65.5.0
watchdog            3.0.0
Werkzeug            3.0.0
```

I would appreciate any help anyone can give me.

https://github.com/kaY-hR/Flask-Template-for-Cloud-Functions
**I create a sample for this question.** Check the source if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Cloud Functions and Lambda do not support multiple endpoints in the usual way. I also found the following website for this problrem.

https://techblg.app/articles/how-to-make-multiple-access-point-with-python-on-cloud-function/

They say that you can wrap it in a single entry point as provided at: https://github.com/av1m/functions-multiple-endpoints